# batch script move files zero bytes same name

Tags: batch-file

Couldn't find a way to do this, looking to store the names of all zero byte files from a folder in a list.

```
if exist *.xml for %%i in (*.xml) do if %%~zi==0 ECHO "%%i" >> list.txt
```

this works but the next step would be to read the list.txt and move all files with the same file name even if it has a different extension, also the other file isn't zero bytes that has the same file name but different extension.

example **12345.html** and **12345.xml** - both files would be moved because the name is the same.

any help would be amazing!

thanks

Answer (score 0):

look at the modifiers in `for /?`. For example `%%~nA` would give you the name without the extension.

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in (list.txt) do (
  echo ---- %%nA ---- files with same basename:
  dir /b "%%~dpnA.*"
)
```

Comment: thanks, but the problem is one file is zero bytes and the other isn't... that's why i look for the zero byte one and add it to the list. then i try and move the zero and other file with the same name but different extension.

Comment: I understood that. Just replace the `dir` command with the corresponding `copy` command.

Comment: i assume i use your script as a second .bat to run after my script correct? didn't work for me, but i suck a batch scripting :)

Comment: obviously it processes the contents of `list.txt`, so - yes, running your code (which creates `list.txt`) before might be a good idea.

Comment: sorry, typo. Try again please.

Comment: my mistake, i had a case of fat fingers! lol thank you so much this worked... i switched  dir /b to del and everything worked perfect.